# How to reset tput text decoration and color

Tags: bash, colors, tput

I have a bash script and I want to be able to highlight critical errors when they occur. To that end I wrote the simple function below

```bash
error() {
# set the text decoration
tput -S <<END
bold
setaf 1
END
# echo the error to stderr
echo "$1" 1>&2
exit 1
}
```

The problem with this code is that the terminal keeps the tput settings after the script exits. I have tried rectifying this in two ways.

1. Add a `tput reset` command before exiting
2. Execute the commands in a subshell

Option 1 doesn't work because it clears the terminal completely, even with the `-x` option.

Option 2 doesn't seem to have any effect, the terminal remains changed even after returning to the main shell. My option 2 code looks like this

```bash
error() {
    bash -C <<EOF
tput -S <<END
bold
setaf 1
END
echo "$1" 1>&2
EOF
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color for various output decorations.

Comment: tr y `tput sgr0`

Comment: Use `tput sgr0` instead of `tput reset`, (and put it in a line after `echo`, before `exit`). `sgr0` resets the text, not the whole terminal. `man 5 terminfo` for a list of terminal capabilities. Subshells aren't relevant. These are terminal control sequences. The terminal changes state depending what is printed to it. The source of the sequence doesn't matter. You can also call tput twice, instead of using a here-doc: `tput bold; tput setaf1`. This also avoids `-S`, which isn't very portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output tput sgr0. I would do:

```
error() {
   tput bold setaf 1 >&2
   echo "ERROR: $*" >&2
   tput sgr0 >&2
}
```

Or "more advanced":

```
error() {
   tput bold setaf 1
   echo "ERROR: $*"
   tput sgr0
} >&2
```

It is odd that you are using `bash -C`, `-C` sets `C` flag in `$-`, which disallows overwriting `an existing file with the >, >&, and <> redirection operators`, see Bash manual about `set` builtin command. Just `bash`, without `-C`, or `bash -s <arg> <arg2>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I missed `sgr0`. I also didn't know about that restriction with  the `-C` option.

Comment: instead of `echo` consider using `printf` for outputting escape codes.  ```printf "ERROR: %s" $*```

Comment: @MERM I will not, `echo` is shorter, and `ERROR` definitely does not start with `-`, so the call is portable.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative for having colored text output without additional packages.

Copy and paste the following lines to your `shell` and call the corresponding function passing it desired message, you will see how cool is the output, quick and simple )

```bash
:<<'ANSIcolorCodes'
Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37
ANSIcolorCodes

# # # Just to have unify messages # # #
type echo_blue  echo_green  echo_red  echo_red_s &> /dev/null || {
  echo_blue(){
   echo -en "\033[0;34m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"
  }
  echo_green(){
   echo -en "\033[0;32m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"
  }
  echo_red(){
   echo -en "\033[0;31m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"
  }
  echo_red_s(){
   echo -en "\033[9;31m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0;0m"
  }
  ### Due to Update #1
  # Define Bold
  echo_bold(){ 
   echo -en "\033[1m$*" ;echo -e "\033[0m"; 
  }
  # Define Blue-Bold, and so on for any other color if needed.
  echo_blue_bold(){ echo_blue `echo_bold "$*"`; }
}
```

Reference link:

- https://github.com/vrej-ab/quick-functions/blob/main/global-functions/_color-echo.function.sh

  - Please feel free to take look at my other public repositories as well https://github.com/vrej-ab?tab=repositories

### Update #1 (01 Sep 2022)

This is the **BOLD** syntax of `echo` command with ANSI.

- `echo -e '\033[1mYOUR_STRING\033[0m'`

Please review and test the provided functions including the updated code part at the end.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and I will probably save this for use in other projects, but in this case I wanted the bold decoration as well which I don't think can be achieved with ansi alone.

Comment: @richbai90 I've also updated my answer that supports BOLD syntax ) see the "Update #1" , good luck.

Comment: Using `tput` to define your color codes is more portable.  i.e.: `Black=$(tput setaf 0` `Red=$(tput setaf 1)` ... `Bold=$(tput bold)` `NC=$(tput sgr0)` NC removes colors.  See above comment on `printf` over `echo`

Comment: so you would have `printf "${Bold}%s${NC}" YOUR_STRING`